# multiple runat=server forms for different processes in masterpage and inherited webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a masterpage and a webform. In my masterpage,I have treeview (for menu) and I put `form tag` in that with `runat=server`.

In my webform, I have registration form created and i put form tag for that with `runat= server`.

When I buid it, its shows error as `One form is allowed in a page`.

How to use multiple `runat=server` forms for different processes in masterpage and inherited webform.

```
<form id="treeview" runat="server">
// treeview code
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You really dont need to add a form tag in the child form i.e. Registration form. During run time both master and Child will be merged together and will render as a single form.

Here goes your Master page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

And here is your Content Or Child page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

  <!-- Any other controls -->

</asp:Content>
```

The following tutorial may help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333650/Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-Master-Pages-in-ASP-NET

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages

Comment: i used the same technique. In registration webpage i have datagrid to display saved candidates. Also in the webpage, I used StreamWriter for export datagrid to pdf by clicking a button and when clicking, it raises error as datagrid must be in a form tag.

Comment: You have to Post your code here OR provide some link to other external site where your code is available.

Answer (score 0):

Master form do you mean master page?

Then no, you cannot have 2 forms running on the same `WebForm`

Comment: Sorry, I meant Master Page